# Fix location of an element in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8

This is a very basic question but I am afraid I didn't find a solution for this. I have an image which comes at the bottom of the layout. I want this image to be located at specific (x,y) location in the layout. Is there a way to do this without defining Grid.Rows for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you will need to use `Canvas` here.

[Check Absolute Layout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207042%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

You can set leftCoord(X) and topCoord(Y) to image like this.

```
    Canvas.SetLeft(image, leftCoord);
    Canvas.Settop(image, topCoord);
```